# Beautiful, outlined font name in Mac OS X

Tags: macos, font

What is the font called in Mac OS X, like the main navigation bar at the top of this site, or something like the font that shows the date at the top right of Mac OS (It has the sort of white outline)?

EDIT: Never mind.  Problem solved.  I edited the text-shadow: attribute in my CSS so that my text was outlined in white.

Comment: If you've solved the problem, please post the solution as an answer, so others can benefit as well - that's what this site is here for, after all.  :)

Answer (score 4):

The default font for Mac OS X is [Lucida Grande](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucida_Grande)

Comment: But is there a way to get it to be outlined in white, giving the sort of "3D" feel?

Comment: The outline, if any, is very faint, and can either be added in a graphics program, or in code when applying the image to a display (as like the menu bar).

Answer (score 2):

Try with [WhatFont](http://chengyinliu.com/whatfont.html).